# Delphi marquee progress bar

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

I've got a query running in a separate thread which takes a while to process, as the users currently has no way of knowing something is being done in the background I wanted to create a progress bar like the third progress bar on this image:

[image]

I've looked at other questions/answers and it looks like a marquee progress bar is what I'm after, I've tried setting my progress bar as marquee but it doesn't do anything. The progress bar properties are as follows:

```
MarqueeInterval = 10
Max = 100
Min = 50
Orientation = pbHorizontal
Position = 50
Smooth = True
State = pbsNormal
Step = 10
Style = pbstMarquee
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or need to change?

My startup code is as follows:

```
procedure TFormMain.SetupForm;
begin
  // Connect to the database
  ConnectToDatabase;

  // Initially hide combo box
  ShowHideComboBox(False);

  ListViewDataType.Columns[0].Width := -1;

  UsingOwnTemplate := False;

  // Initial page is the welcome page
  PageControl.ActivePage := TabWelcome;
end;

procedure TFormMain.ConnectToDatabase;
var
  FullPath : String;
  CompanyName: String;
begin
  // Create the database connection
  DBConnection := TFDConnection.Create(nil);

  // Get the folder path
  FullPath := GetCurrentDir;

  DatabasePath := FullPath;

  // Setup the database connection
  with DBConnection do begin
    DriverName := 'MSAcc';
    Params.Add(Format('Database=%s', [DatabasePath]));
    Params.Add('StringFormat=UNICODE');
    Connected := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg yes this is for `Vcl`.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code related to another thread. I just see database components which are being used in the main thread. These components simply cannot be used across thread boundaries. So either you posted us the wrong unrelated code, or you are in fact running your query in the main thread, not another thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a `TProgressBar` and set its `Style` property to `pbstMarquee`.
It should be all, if it doesn't work, make sure that:

1. The main thread is not blocked (Is the query really executed in another thread or is there any other reason why the main thread could be blocked?)
2. The project is compiled with the "Enable runtime themes" option enabled (Otherwise, `pbstMarquee` will not work)
   [image: enable runtime themes option]

Comment: Bingo, I've enabled the user runtime themes and it works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @WiliamCardoso That's usually enabled by default on new projects.

Comment: @JerryDodge I think I was messing around with it a couple weeks back because I thought it did something to the appearance of the program and never changed it back :/

Comment: @WiliamCardoso "*I thought it did something to the appearance of the program*" - it does, by enabling Windows' own built-in UI theming, which involves enabling a newer version of the ComCtrl32 library that implements new UI controls, such as the ProgressBar's marquee style.

Answer (score 3):

Just drop a `TProgressBar` on your form and use the Object Inspector to set the `Style` property to `pbstMarquee`. That's all!

[image: Screenshot of progress bar]

Comment: Ok, I've just tried that on a new project and it works fine, so it must be my project :(. The progress bar is being put on a PageControl TTab on my original project would this do anything to stop the animation being visible?

Comment: No, a page control should not be an issue.

Comment: Are you sure your computation really is performed in a separate thread (not the main/GUI thread)? Because if you accidentally perform the computation in the main/GUI thread, the GUI will not repaint itself or respond to user input.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The query starts when you select an excel file which it will then read, however even when the program starts up (before you have any option to select a file) the progress bar doesn't animate.

Comment: @WiliamCardoso: Remove one part of your application at a time, until you reach the state of an essentially empty VCL application with only the progress bar.

Comment: I will try this now and see what happens!